# How to use SQLite db file location in select?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to use the main database file location in function (replace or other) as input data. How can i get it?

> for example: replace('c:\temp\main.db','main.db','')

I'm creating a database script for command line use under win10.

`.database` command result seems to be fine, but how to use in replace input?

EDIT: I have to use the location as variable, because i run the script from command line, recursively in a lot of directories with a lot of small databases, so i can't use constant value in replace.

The cmd line command:

> forfiles /p c:\temp /m files.db /s /c "cmd /c c:\sqlite3.exe @path < c:\BookDbDataCopy.txt"

I want to use the path in the select as variable.

Comment: Since your script will have opened the SQLite database, it already knows where it is located. It doesn't have to ask the database.

Comment: Sorry, my question was inaccurate, i updated that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it :)

create table path (a text);
.mode csv
.output 'c:\data.csv'
.databases
.import 'c:\data.csv' path

The solution: 
 - create a table for the path
 - write the command output in file
 - import the file in table
 - select the table in replace variable :)

select replace((select a from path where a like 'main%'),'main: c:\',''), t.* from path;